# How to disable Woocommerce Setup Wizard?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to disable the Woocommerce Setup Wizard but not having any luck. On a WP MU install it asks users to install plugins which is not possible for subsites. And then it asks admins to choose a theme that’s located on wordpress.org so that installation is not possible either. I need to disable this wizard. I am using the code below but it does not work. I am still being redirected to the setup wizard when I go to Woocommerce>Dashboard.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard', 'disable_wizard' );
function disable_wizard(){
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should prevent the wizard from triggering:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_automatic_wizard_redirect', '__return_true' );
```

If you want to allow WooCommerce to trigger the wizard later, you can enable it again:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_automatic_wizard_redirect', '__return_false' );
```